# How to get the average of the last cells in a column based on the last month?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that contains an amount in column D and the week number(A), month number (B), and year(C).  How do I get the average of the last month's amount (D)?  So in the example below, I am looking for the average of D251 to D254 based on last month (Column B) 7.  Then next month, with it's September, The same cell would average all the "Amounts" in column D for the month of last month, Aug 8th.  I hope that all makes sense.

How do I get the average of the last month's amount (D)?

[image]

Comment: Google sheets and excel are two different applications and use different formula. Which are you using?

Comment: Google Sheets.  Sorry.  Usually, the formulas are similar.  Should I remove the excel tag?

Comment: No, it can be usd on either one.

Comment: Removed the tags, because if you want a Google Sheets solution you should use Sheets tags to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AverageIF, or possibly AverageIFs (plural) to account for prior year. I updated my example. You also might consider a different structure/column for time that combines Year_Month. See example in sheet.

Formula used:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(D:D,B:B,if(B2=1,12,B2-1),C:C,if(B2=1,C2-1,C2)),"First Period")
```

[See this example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j_XAFrQeJnEm3jOzs3cb51rYU4JPbPNj-OthaKHs7NM/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Sorry, I think AverageIFS (plural) is needed to account for change in years. You also might think of combining month and year.

Comment: Oh nice!  I'm checking out the sheet now.  Could I use something like =TEXT(EDATE(H2,-1),"MMMM YYYY") to reference the time?
H2 would be =TEXT(TODAY(),"MM/YYYY")

Comment: That's it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(FILTER(A2:D,B2:B=MAX(B2:B)),,4))
```