# Converting Multidimensional Arrays Into A Spill Range

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, excel-formula, spill-range

I've been posting a lot of Array/Spill Range answers lately trying to generate non-vba/App Script solutions. However, I've run into situations where I have arrays within arrays that aren't spilling as I expect. [This specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759512/how-to-transpose-duplicated-data-in-rows-into-columns/68760465) caused me to post this question.

Synopsis of issue I was addressing:

- Starting values of 5 columns of data in `A:E`.
- OP wants unique list of first four columns (`A:D`)
- Transpose `Column E` values to the right.

### Sample Starting Data:

| Col A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | Bravo | Charlie | Delta | 1 |
| Alpha | Bravo | Charlie | Delta | 2 |
| Alpha | Bravo | Charlie | Delta | 3 |
| Delta | Echo | Foxtrot | Gulf | 4 |
| Delta | Echo | Foxtrot | Gulf | 5 |
| Delta | Echo | Foxtrot | Gulf | 6 |
| XRay | Yankee | Zulu | Delta | 9 |
| XRay | Yankee | Zulu | Delta | 4 |
| XRay | Yankee | Zulu | Delta | 2 |
| XRay | Yankee | Zulu | Delta | 1 |
| XRay | Yankee | Zulu | Delta | 3 |
| Alpha | Bravo | Charlie | Delta | 4 |

### Desired Outcome:

| i | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | Bravo | Charlie | Delta | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |  |
| Delta | Echo | Foxtrot | Gulf | 4 | 5 | 6 |  |  |
| XRay | Yankee | Zulu | Delta | 9 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 |

My [solution spreadsheet is posted here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g6tQrcB44Kvabaj4ng?e=jPsCG4) or see [google sheets version that you can edit in duplicate tabs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L7bU9npzhvcEmvOa_LZ2xSdIPzK87DCnGUrUUHXFxnI/edit#gid=0).

I can easily get the first four columns using the below formula in cell `i1`

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:D,NOT(ISBLANK((A:A)))))
```

I can then use the function below to create the transposed values to spill out to the right (as shown above) in `M1`.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E:E,(NOT(ISBLANK(E:E))*(A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D=I1&J1&K1&L1))))
```

My challenge is getting this above formula to spill **down** to match the first four columns. Obviously, I can drag the formula down (which was my proposal), **but how can I make this formula dynamic that spills down similar to the first four columns?** The below formula seemed to me like it should work, but it throws an error:

```
=FILTER(TRANSPOSE(FILTER($E:$E,(NOT(ISBLANK($E:$E))*($A:$A&$B:$B&$C:$C&$D:$D=I1:I999&J1:J999&K1:K999&L1:L999)))),NOT(ISBLANK(L1:L999)))
```

Bonus/Similar question: I experienced a similar problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68745359/how-to-get-the-average-of-the-last-cells-in-a-column-based-on-the-last-month/68745462#68745462). If you can figure how how to make `column E` in [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j_XAFrQeJnEm3jOzs3cb51rYU4JPbPNj-OthaKHs7NM/edit#gid=0) a dynamic spill range, I'll upvote the answer.

Comment: I saw that question, and worked on it for a couple hours before deciding it would not be possible without LAMBDA().  Array formula do not like the dual iteration.

Comment: Thanks for trying.

Comment: Yes, LAMBDA is the answer.  And [`BYROW`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb) (Insiders only atm, and also gears of Lambda)

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(data,FILTER(A:E,A:A<>""),
column1,UNIQUE(FILTER(A:D,A:A<>"")),
tableC1,FILTER(A:A&B:B&C:C&D:D,A:A<>""),
tableC2,FILTER(E:E,A:A<>""),
table,CHOOSE({1,2},tableC1,tableC2),
utableC1,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(tableC1)),
v,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(IF(tableC1=utableC1,INDEX(table,,2),"")),1),
seqrv,SEQUENCE(ROWS(v)),
x,MMULT(LEN(v)--(v<>""),SIGN(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(v))))-1,
y,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(seqrv)<seqrv),x)+seqrv,
column2,IFERROR(MID(TEXTJOIN(" ",1,v),y,x),""),
IF(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(data))<=COLUMNS(column1),column1,column2))
```

This results in the desired spill result, but the data of column E is joined in one cell instead of spilling to the right. I hope that's acceptable. The result would look like this using the function above:

[image: Stackoverflow]

PS partial credits to Mark Fitzgerald for posting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594673/12634230)

Comment: Thanks for the post. I upvoted but did not accept as the objective is indeed to maintain the spill range going out to the right, versus grouping them in a cell as you did in column k. It is cool that you were able to get everything into one cell. That'd be nice to have, but at this point, a satisfactory answer can have two formulas in two cells: `i1` (in my original sheet which is working fine) and then somehow getting the formula in `M1` to spill down while maintaining the spill range out to the right.

Comment: Not for readibility, but for the effort: +:)

Comment: @T.M. yea I thought about chopping up the answer a bit with some photoshop as that's a lot to absorb! But it was indeed a good effort, and PB appears to be relatively new so don't want to be overly critical (I know *my* answers didn't win any beautiful/neat awards when my SO rating was 1,426 )

Answer (score 0):

Over two years later, it occurred to me that with the newer functions, I can now answer my own question. The challenge is getting a dynamic horizontal range which I solved with [MakeArray](https://exceljet.net/functions/makearray-function).

Unfortunately because google sheets and Excel use two function names to do the same thing, I couldn't get a dynamic formula for both (Sheets uses`split` while Excel uses `textsplit`)

Each formula expects let parameters of the full range filtered by one column, a character to represent cutting data the last column number before transposing

### Google Sheets

[Sample file here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mGQQLOUYFICBrzceW0JAzvWAoUOxuCZ2blxK345FjuY/edit#gid=2100307022)

```
=LET(alldata,FILTER(A:E,A:A<>""),    zSplitter,"?", zColumnCount,4,
allNames,HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(alldata,SEQUENCE(1,zColumnCount))),
zNames,UNIQUE(allNames),
keysFiltered, BYROW(zNames,LAMBDA(eRow,TEXTJOIN(zSplitter,TRUE,eRow))),
keysFull,BYROW(allNames,LAMBDA(eRow,TEXTJOIN(zSplitter,TRUE,eRow))),
splitNums,BYROW(keysFiltered,LAMBDA(eRow,TEXTJOIN(zSplitter,TRUE,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(alldata,zColumnCount+1),keysFull=eRow)))),
zElementCount,BYROW(splitNums,LAMBDA(eRow, LEN(eRow)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(eRow,zSplitter,""))+1)), zMaxCol,MAX(zElementCount),
zSideArray,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(zNames),zMaxCol,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(tempRng,INDEX(splitNums,r,1),tempSplitRng,SPLIT(tempRng,zSplitter),IF(c>CHOOSEROWS(zElementCount,r),"",CHOOSECOLS(tempSplitRng,c))))),
HSTACK(zNames,zSideArray))
```

[image]

### Excel

```
=LET(alldata,FILTER(A:E,A:A<>""),zSplitter,"?", zColumnCount,4,
allNames,HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(alldata,SEQUENCE(1,zColumnCount))),
zNames,UNIQUE(allNames),
keysFiltered, BYROW(zNames,LAMBDA(eRow,TEXTJOIN(zSplitter,TRUE,eRow))),
keysFull,BYROW(allNames,LAMBDA(eRow,TEXTJOIN(zSplitter,TRUE,eRow))),
splitNums,BYROW(keysFiltered,LAMBDA(eRow,TEXTJOIN(zSplitter,TRUE,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(alldata,zColumnCount+1),keysFull=eRow)))),
zElementCount,BYROW(splitNums,LAMBDA(eRow, LEN(eRow)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(eRow,zSplitter,""))+1)), zMaxCol,MAX(zElementCount),
zSideArray,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(zNames),zMaxCol,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(tempRng,INDEX(splitNums,r,1),tempSplitRng,TEXTSPLIT(tempRng,zSplitter),IF(c>CHOOSEROWS(zElementCount,r),"",CHOOSECOLS(tempSplitRng,c))))),
HSTACK(zNames,zSideArray))
```